# Number of ways of distributing $k$ balls of different colors into $n$ bins with a certain requirements

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question that makes me very confused even if I consider both "block" technique and "twelvefold way"

Suppose I have balls of $k$ different colours, $a(j)$ of each colour for $j \le k$. In each colour, the ball is **indistinguishable** and $a(j)$ is different for each colour. How many ways can I distribute all balls, $\sum_j a(j)$, *uniformly* into $n$ **indistinguishable** bins, where $n>k$ and $n$ is a multiple of $k$, with the requirement that there are exactly $j$ colours of balls in each bin as well, where $0\le j \le k$?

Most balls to bins problems assume that there is only one color, but this problem has one more difficulties on both requiring equal amount of balls and different colors. Clearly, some extremes are impossible and the answer is 0 for the case when $j=0$ or $j=k$.

Can anyone provide solution or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "equally"? Uniformly, that is each bin receives the same total number of balls? And your condition of equally distributing $j$ colours is not clear either; I take this to mean $j$ specific colours are required to be "equally distributed", but I don't see why this should imply that there are $j$ colours in each bin. There are $k-j$ colours for which there is no "equally distributed" requirement, so you don't control those. It would be good to give at least one concrete example of what you intend to count.